# How do I get rid of the borders in the top left cell of this table?

Tags: html, css

My HTML is:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:40%; ">
            No Border here, just white background
        </th>
        <th style="width:60%; background-color:gray" colspan="3">
            Superheading</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="left" style="width:40%">Options</th>
        <th style="width:20%">Title2</th>
        <th style="width:20%">Title3</th>
        <th style="width:20%">Title4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Option1</td>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How do I remove the border in the top left cell ie the cell that contains "No Border here, just white background".

Thanks.

Comment: Somehow I did not find any border.. Am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t0sqb41u/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <style>
        table, table th, table td {
            border:1px solid black;
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }
    </style>
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:40%; background-color:white;" class="border-less">&nbsp;</th>
                <th style="width:60%;text-align:center" colspan="3">Assumed Growth Rate</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th align="left" style="width:40%">Options</th>
                <th style="width:20%">Title2</th>
                <th style="width:20%">Title3</th>
                <th style="width:20%">Title4</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Option1</td>
                <td>val1</td>
                <td>val2</td>
                <td>val3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.border-less {
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to the fiddle I created in an answer below (http://jsfiddle.net/5fpuohsn/), but with white borders rather than no borders. Could anyone explain what the functional difference is between my answer and this one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to add :

```
style="border: none";
```

on th tag or the tr tag containing the headers.Depending on what you need..

Comment: @SamJolly please could you share a fiddle or working demo and there is no border in your code - http://jsfiddle.net/qk01je4n/

Comment: Thank you Mary. If you would like to put it as an answer then I will mark it as such. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[**This fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5fpuohsn/) uses CSS and a '`.borderless`' class.

However, if you wanted to stick to inline styling, you could do this:

```
<th style="width:40%; border:none;">
```

Comment: Thanks, but... the table border still seems there though.